Simple LCA with Brightway2.5 on Ecoinvent 3.10
Hi Brightway and LCA enthusiasts,
I am trying to run a simple LCA on Ecoinvent3.10 using Brightway2.5. I am getting inconsistent results, described at the bottom of the code. Can someone please take a look and let me know what I got wrong?
I am writing here for help after spending a significant amount of time following the documentation and running out of energy to figure out what is lacking.
Note: if you're here to help and try to run the code, you'll need a valid Ecoinvent license, username and password to download the data and access Ecoquery with impact results.
Python
Version 3.12.3
Packages
bw_migrations = "0.2"
bw_processing = "0.9.6"
bw-simapro-csv = "0.2.1"
bw2analyzer = "0.11.8"
bw2calc = "2.0.dev18"
bw2data = "4.0.dev47"
bw2io = "0.9.dev30"
bw2parameters = "1.1.0"
fs = "2.4.16"
pypardiso = "^0.4.6"
ecoinvent-interface = "^2.5"

Environment variables
Requires ECOINVENT_USERNAME and ECOINVENT_PASSWORD set
Code
import logging
import os
import pathlib
import uuid
from typing import Dict, List

import bw2calc as bc
import bw2data as bd
import bw2io as bi
import ecoinvent_interface as ei

DEFAULT_EI_RELEASE_VERSION = "3.10"

logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def full_setup_from_scratch(ei_release_version: str = DEFAULT_EI_RELEASE_VERSION):
    # Set the Brightway project
    bd.projects.set_current("sapiobw")

    # Download the Ecoinvent release
    ei_settings = ei.Settings(username=os.environ["ECOINVENT_USERNAME"], password=os.environ["ECOINVENT_PASSWORD"])
    ei.EcoinventRelease(ei_settings).get_release(ei_release_version, "cutoff", ei.release.ReleaseType.ecospold)

    # Import the biosphere matrix, after this, `bd.databases` will list the biosphere matrix as available
    # len(bd.methods) == 722 after this step
    if "biosphere3" not in list(bd.databases):
        bi.bw2setup()

    # Import the Ecoinvent data as a Brightway database
    ei_name = f"ecoinvent_{ei_release_version}_cutoff"
    if ei_name not in list(bd.databases):
        ei_path = os.path.join(pathlib.Path.home(), f".local/share/EcoinventInterface/cache/ecoinvent {ei_release_version}_cutoff_ecoSpold02/datasets")

        # Create the importer (will extract the XML)
        ei_importer = bi.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(ei_path, ei_name)

        # In some cases, we may get an error related to “unlinked exchanges”. This is because there are some biosphere flows used in ecoinvent that do not exist in the BW25 biosphere3 database (and, consequently, in our LCIA methods). The best we can do is to import these unlinked flows into another biosphere database. If these flows are important to you, you should do further matching or modify the relevant LCIA methods to include them.
        ei_importer.add_unlinked_flows_to_biosphere_database()

        # Convert the database into something compatible with Brightway2.5 architecture
        ei_importer.apply_strategies()

        # Tell us how it went
        ei_importer.statistics()

        # Write to the database under ./databases.db, should be about 1.3GB
        ei_importer.write_database()

db_eco = bd.Database("ecoinvent_3.10_cutoff")
results = db_eco.search("transport, freight, lorry >32 metric ton")
# I am taking "transport, freight, lorry >32 metric ton, EURO5' (ton kilometer, BR, None)" which has key ('ecoinvent_3.10_cutoff', 'dfff989ae2da13afeb45e490433f55d8')
impact_method = ('EF v3.1', 'climate change', 'global warming potential (GWP100)')
result = bd.get_node(database="ecoinvent_3.10_cutoff", code="dfff989ae2da13afeb45e490433f55d8")
demand = {result: 1}
lca = bc.LCA(demand, impact_method)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
lca.score

And I get a score of 3.893050517434942 (assuming it's kgCO2eq/ton * km). The corresponding EcoQuery page is transport, freight, lorry >32 metric ton, EURO5 - Brazil - transport, freight, lorry >32 metric ton, EURO5 | ecoQuery (ecoinvent.org) with 9.1090e-2 kgCO2eq/ton*km

StackOverflow suggested this article Brightway2 and ecoinvent 3.10 -- unlinked exchanges as related to mine.
It turns out this was the answer (don't ask me why). See Chris Mutel's answer here
Setting up a project with
import bw2data as bd
import bw2io as bi
bd.projects.set_current(<your project name>)
bi.import_ecoinvent_release("3.10", "cutoff")

linked exchanges to biosphere flows properly (probably that was not the case with how I did that before) and results are now consistent.
Also note that the methods will then be prefixed with "ecoinvent-3.10". Example:
[
    ('ecoinvent-3.10', 'EF v3.1', 'climate change', 'global warming potential (GWP100)'),
    ('ecoinvent-3.10', 'ReCiPe 2016 v1.03, midpoint (H)', 'climate change', 'global warming potential (GWP100)')
]

